# Issue with scala backticks in pattern matching

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, pattern-matching, backticks

I have two sealed abstract classes,A and B and their subclasses. I am trying to use them in pattern matching as:

```
(a,b) match {
   case (`a1`, `b1`) => ....
}
```

a1,a2...b1,b2.... are subtypes of A,B respectively.

while IDE(Intellij) can detect `a1`, but it is unable to detect `b1`. All imports are defined well.

Is it wrong way of using back ticks?

Comment: a1 a2 b1 b2 are instances of the subclases or the name of the subclass, can you put a larger example with the instanciation of a1 and b1?

Comment: Also, are the clases of a b a1 etc case classes?

Comment: And what error you get with the code

Comment: Have you tried binding the vars like case ```(v1 : `a1`,  v2 : `b1`) ``` ?